# How to assert that code won't compile in a test?

Tags: testing, rust

I'm currently writing some unsafe code that requires some degree of manually managing lifetimes, and exposing those lifetimes to external users. I've been writing tests, and while it's pretty easy to write tests to verify the correctness of code that compiles (at least to the extent that the potential for undefined behavior allows), I've been looking to ensure certain types of unsound code can't compile.

Say I have the following contrived example:

```rust
pub struct MyBox<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
}

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        MyBox {
            ptr: Box::into_raw(Box::new(t)),
        }
    }
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &*self.ptr }
    }
}
impl<T> Drop for MyBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(self.ptr) }
    }
}

fn test<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
    MyBox::new(7).get()
}
```

How can I ensure that the `test` function continues to fail to compile from rust's test framework?

Obviously, just throwing the erroneous code into a separate file and using the actual test function as glorified build script works, but that gets really boilerplatey and awkward, especially when there are more than just one or two bad examples I would like to test. If it helps, I don't care about the specifics of the error, just that an error exists.

Comment: Are you asking to be able to test code (which compiles) that is also in the same file as some other that doesn't compile?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I would like to be able to test some code that compiles, at the same time as testing that some other code in the same project continues to not compile. In other words, I'd like testing to only succeed if some code, using types from the crate, doesn't compile successfully. If the erroring code could be within the same file as the compiling code that would be most convenient, but I do know that's probably impossible without compiler support, and to the extent of my knowledge, none exists.

Comment: I don't think Rust supports testing that code doesn't compile, you'd need to separately run another instance (process) of the Rust compiler and interpret the results from that. This approach would require separate files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it as a doctest with [`compile_fail`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/documentation-tests.html?highlight=compile_fail#attributes) attr so that you can write multiple tests that expect to fail at the same time in a comment.

````
/// ```compile_fail,E0515
/// use path_to::MyBox;
///
/// fn test<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
///     MyBox::new(7).get()
/// }
/// ```
fn _doc_test() {}
````

`,E0515` indicates the error number you expect, which avoids any other errors that would make the test false negative. (This error number check will be ignored if cargo is not running as nightly)

Note that this requires your crate to be a `lib` instead of a `bin`, as `bin` is not currently supported by doctests. (issue [#50784](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50784))

Comment: +1 for the `,E0515` but why would you introduce a new function for that instead of documenting something it applies to.

Comment: @cafce25 Assuming there are 20 tests that are expected to fail, I prefer it to be placed at the end of the file rather than above the `impl` block (just like normal unit tests are placed under `mod tests`). For the compiler, this never-used private function will not appear in the binary eventually.

Comment: Note that error numbers are unstable. I would not add the error number.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The error number check does require `nightly` to work, but if run as `stable`, the check is simply ignored and does not result in a compile error for using the unstable feature.

Comment: @Sprite I meant unstable as "can change without warning", not as "requires nightly".

Comment: Does tooling do anything with the error code?  It seems to be ignored.

Comment: @Sprite How do you identify the feature/issue# that implements the expected error number attribute (the `,E0515` thing)? I searched in https://unstablerust.dev/ but didn't find anything.

Comment: @roy Just copy it from the failure output of rustc.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, if you do care about the specific error the compiler emits, is to use [trybuild](https://github.com/dtolnay/trybuild).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your test function in a doc-test with the [`compile_fail`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/documentation-tests.html?highlight=compile_fail#attributes) annotation:

````
pub struct MyBox<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
}

/// ```compile_fail
/// fn test<'a>() -> &'a i32 {
///     playground::MyBox::new(7).get()
/// }
/// ```
impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        MyBox {
            ptr: Box::into_raw(Box::new(t)),
        }
    }
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        unsafe { &*self.ptr }
    }
}
impl<T> Drop for MyBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe { Box::from_raw(self.ptr) }
    }
}
````

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b5d1257a6c9cbe8f1f211b27604f9dd)

Note though that you can only test public functions that way.